# navigator.geolocation.watchPosition empty position

Tags: javascript, geolocation, gps, w3c-geolocation

navigator.geolocation.watchPosition success callback is always called with an empty position object. What am I missing?
Tried the following setup (location granted, https):

- Chrome Desktop 95.0.4638.54
- Chrome Android 94.0.4606.85

```js
function errorCb(error) {
    console.log('errorCb() ' + error.code + ", " + error.message);
}
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    const options = {
        enableHighAccuracy: false,
        timeout: 5000,
        maximumAge: 0
    };
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(position => {
        console.log("pos: " + JSON.stringify(position));  // always displays "pos: {}"
    }, errorCb, options);
}
```

Comment: Because the object that's returned can't be stringified, and can't be placed in a string. If do `console.log(position)` you'll see the object that is returned and whos properties you can access.

Comment: @Andy this is it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to Andys comment the position object provided can't be stringified. Access the object directly:

```
var coords = position.coords;
var latitude = coords.latitude;
var longitude = coords.longitude;
```